# How do I override a get()/all()/filter() function in Django for lazy deletion?

Tags: django, django-models, lazy-evaluation

I am developing a course registration site in Django, and I want to allow for lazy deletion of objects; when an object is deleted, it is merely marked as deleted, but not really taken out of the database.

I am adding a new boolean property in user profiles called "deleted." Subsequently, I want to override a Model's get/all/filter function(s) to exclude deleted objects when retrieving sets of data.

How do I override the default get function(s)? Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Override `get_query_set` for your model manager

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#modifying-initial-manager-querysets

```
class MyManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(MyManager, self).get_query_set().exclude(deleted=True)
```

Comment: Is it not `get_queryset`? ref: [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/managers/#modifying-initial-manager-querysets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/managers/#modifying-initial-manager-querysets)